# Hacker Rank: semi-space copy Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Problem description:

> There is a string, `s`, of lowercase English letters that is repeated infinitely many times. Given an integer, `n`, find and print the number of letter `a`'s in the first `n` letters of the infinite string.

I had a function that works and passes the test in hacker rank, but the only test that I have an issue with is that it runs out of memory. I thought it would be from the while loop, but I don't understand where the issue is coming from.

**Error:**

```
semi-space copy Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

**repeatedString.js:**

```js
// Repeated String
function repeatedString(s, n) {
  // WRITE YOUR CODE HERE
  let infiniteString = s;

  // String Length (Too Small)
  if (infiniteString.length < n) {
    while (infiniteString.length < n) {
      infiniteString += s;
    }
  }

  // Frequency Count
  let frequencyCount = 0;

  // Iterate Over String
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (infiniteString[i] === 'a') {
      frequencyCount += 1;
    }
  }

  return frequencyCount;
};
```

Comment: If the task is to count the number of a's in the resulting string, then there's definetly a simpler solution than to actually create the repeated string. Hint: If "aa" gets repeated 1.000 times, how many a's are there?

Comment: What is this supposed to do?

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/repeated-string/problem?h_r=internal-search

Comment: The only special case you need to deal with is if `n` isn't a multiple of `s.length`.

Comment: You just need to compute the number of full strings. Multiple by the number of a's in the full string. Then deal with the partial string at the end. Division and modulo.

Comment: Could you give us an example of calling the function which causes the error, I can't make it fail.

Comment: @AHaworth, the script runs in a memory-limited nodejs instance. running `s='a';n=100000000` you may get the error

Comment: Thanks, it took another nought or two but ran out in the end. You need to rethink your algorithm - the word 'infinite' describing the string is a clue - it can't be done by building the relevant string in every case on a finite machine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems (to me) to be due to the memory needed to fill the string, if `n` goes over cca 70,000,000 (with a single character for `s`), the string will require more memory than is available.

This is intentional IMHO, as the challenge authors want you to not use the *lazy™* way of getting the value, but writing an actual efficient algorithm.

So you'll likely need to calculate the number of `a`'s  in the input multiply it by the number of times it fits fully in `s`, and then figure out how many in the remainder.

This way you're not creating the string.

### Spoiler

```js
function repeatedString(s, n) {
    // Write your code here
    
    if (s === '') return 0;
    
    // string longer or equal to n
    if (s.length >= n) {
        s = s.substr(0, n);
        // return s.split('a').length -1
        return s.match(/a/g)?.length || 0;
    }
    
    // num full instances
    let f = Math.floor(n/s.length)
    
    // calculate number of a's in full matches
    let nf = s.match(/a/g)?.length * f || 0;
    
    // get the remainder length
    let r = n - f * s.length;
    
    // no remainder? return a's in full matches only
    if (r === 0 ) return nf;
    
    // get number of a's in remainder
    let rf = s.substr(0,r).match(/a/g)?.length || 0;
    
    return nf + rf
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hackerank Repeated string solution in php (pass all test cases)

```
<?php
function repeatedString($s, $n) {
  $a = 0;
  for($i = 0; $i < strlen($s);$i++)
   if($s[$i] == 'a')
   $a++;
  $repeated_string = intval($n/strlen($s));
  $repeated_string *= $a;
  if($n%strlen($s)){
    $r = $n%strlen($s);
    for($i = 0; $i < $r;$i++)
      if($s[$i] == 'a')
      $repeated_string++;
  }
  return $repeated_string;
}
echo repeatedString("a", 1000000000000);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Repeated String solution in javascript

```js
function repeatedString(s, n) {
  let a = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
    if (s[i] == "a") a++;
  let repeated_string = Math.floor(n / s.length);
  repeated_string *= a;
  if (n % s.length) {
    let r = n % s.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < r; i++)
      if (s[i] == "a") repeated_string++;
  }
  return repeated_string;
}
console.log(repeatedString("a", 1000000000000));
```